# RubyOnRails and MySQL2 return error 500 sporadically

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, amazon-web-services, mysql2

I have a RubyOnRails application hosted on an Amazon EC2 server (with Elastic Load Balancer) that communicates with the database hosted on Amazon RDS.

I'm having trouble to fix the error 500 returned by the aplication sporadically:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `fields' for nil:NilClass):
 activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:216:in `exec_query'
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are trying to call a method on a on an active record object that returned nil.

for instance if you have a model called page and are trying to get the fields for that page i.e. Page.find(params[:id]).fields however there os no record in the DB for a page with that id so you are trying to call the method fields on it which does not exist for that instance of your page model.

try wrapping the method call inside and if/else statement to call the method fields only if page(or whatever class you are trying to call it on) is not nil.